# Use sed to inject another sed call in a string

Tags: bash, sed, zsh

I want to inject a `sed` call in following string from a minified `.js` file

`\n\ttar -xf abc.tar.gz\n\tTAR_EXIT`

Right before the `\n\tTAR_EXIT` I want to inject:

```
\n\tsed -i 's/if(this._eService.isBuilt)/if(!this._eService.isBuilt)/' abc*/out/logs/main/server.main.js
```

So the final result looks like

`\n\ttar -xf abc.tar.gz\n\tsed -i 's/if(this._eService.isBuilt)/if(!this._eService.isBuilt)/' abc*/out/logs/main/server.main.js\n\tTAR_EXIT`

I am on zsh but I can switch to bash as well.

This string is a part of a complete bash script enclosed inside a 1-line javascript file that is fetched from the web, which is why I am looking at using `sed` to replace the characters.

I have already looked into various posts here regarding mass-escape of regex characters
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29626460#29626460) so far has come close but the string is still not being matched by sed

The baseline for what I want to achieve looks like this in bash:

```bash
sed -i "s|\n\ttar -xf abc.tar.gz\n\tTAR_EXIT|\n\ttar -xf abc.tar.gz\n\tsed -i 's/if(this._eService.isBuilt)/if(!this._eService.isBuilt)/' abc*/out/logs/main/server.main.js\n\tTAR_EXIT|g"
```

Here I have used `|` as the delimiter.

I even disabled the history operation using `set +H` to escape the `!`'s but this is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10467453/6437140 by @Gurpartap Singh has solved it for my usecase.

The wrapper script

```bash
#!/bin/bash
file="${3:--}"
sed "s/$(echo $1 | sed -e 's/\([[\/.*]\|\]\)/\\&/g')/$(echo $2 | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g')/g" $file
```